# Category Page Sort by Popularity (PHP + Opencart)

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

I have an open cart site that displays all the products on one page (if the user chooses to see this page).  I am attempting to have it sort by popularity limited to 1 specific product category (Category id:23) instead of what is currently sorts by which is the latest added.

I know that Opencart already has the popularity function embedded since you can view reports in the admin section based on Most viewed as well as most purchased.

See Category Page below:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>

<div id="content">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center">
    <?php if (trim($heading_title)=="Kippahs"){$heading_title="Kippah Gallery";} ?>
    <?php if (trim($heading_title)=="Wedding Glass Art"){$heading_title="Wedding Glass Gallery";} ?>
    <?php if (trim($heading_title)=="Judaic Art"){$heading_title="Judaica Art Gallery";} ?>
    <?php if (trim($heading_title)=="Artist"){$heading_title="Meet Our Artists";} ?>
    <?php if (trim($heading_title)=="Ketubahs"){$heading_title="Scroll Down to View All Our Ketubahs on One Page";} ?>

<?php if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=='_route_=all-our-ketubot/' || substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],0,23)=='_route_=all-our-ketubot' || substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],0,15)=='_route_=ketubah' || substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],0,24)=='_route_=meet-our-artists' || substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],0,24)=='_route_=our-most-amazing' || substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],0,24)=='_route_=the-interfaith-k'){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        <!--
        function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
        eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
        if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
        }
        //-->
    </script>


<?php include("selector.php"); ?>


<?php } ?>

<div style="width:800px;">
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">

    <table style="margin-top:-35px;margin-bottom:0px;padding:10px;">
      <tr>
      <?php
  if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!='_route_=ketubahs'){
  ?>
        <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
        <td><img class="catimg" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" width="150" height="150" /></td>      
        <?php } 
                                                   }
        ?>
        <?php if ($description) { ?>
        <td valign="top" class="headcat"><?php echo $description; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div><!--[if lt IE 7]><br /><![endif]-->
    <?php if (!$categories && !$products) { ?>
    <div class="content"><?php echo $text_error; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
  if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!='_route_=ketubahs'){
  ?>
    <!--<?php /* if ($categories) { */ ?> -->
    <?php if ($categories && $heading_title!="Scroll Down to View All Our Ketubahs on One Page") { ?>
    <table class="listC" cellspacing="7">
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($categories); $i = $i + 4) {
       $numpages=sizeof($products);
      ?>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) { ?>
        <td width="25%"><?php if (isset($categories[$j])) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $categories[$j]['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $categories[$j]['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $categories[$j]['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $categories[$j]['name']; ?>" style="margin-bottom: 3px;" /></a><br />
          <a href="<?php echo $categories[$j]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $categories[$j]['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <?php } 
                                                   }
    ?>
    <?php if ($products) { ?>
 <!-- <div class="sort"> -->
      <div class="sort" <?php if ($heading_title=="Scroll Down to View All Our Ketubahs on One Page") { echo "style='margin-top:-40px;'"; } ?> >
      <div class="div1">
        <select name="sort" onchange="location = this.value">
          <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
          <?php if (($sort . '-' . $order) == $sorts['value']) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="div2"><?php echo $text_sort; ?></div>
    </div>
    <table class="listC" cellspacing="7">
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($products); $i = $i + 4) {
       $numpages=sizeof($products);
      ?>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) { ?>
        <td width="25%">
<?php if (isset($products[$j])) { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $products[$j]['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $products[$j]['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?>" width="210px" height="210px" /></a><br /><Br />
          <div style="margin-top:-15px;"><a href="<?php echo $products[$j]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?></a><br />
<?php       if($products[$j]['artist'] != 'Rosenthal, Gary' and $products[$j]['artist'] != 'Jessy Judaica' and !empty($products[$j]['artist'])){
            $artist_fname=substr($products[$j]['artist'],strpos($products[$j]['artist'],",")+1);
            $artist_lname=substr($products[$j]['artist'],0,strpos($products[$j]['artist'],","));
        $artist_fullname=trim($artist_fname)." ".trim($artist_lname);
        if (trim($products[$j]['artist'])=="Zeev") {
        $artist_fullname="Ze&#39;ev"; }
        if (trim($products[$j]['artist'])=="This is not a Ketubah") {
        $artist_fullname="This is not a Ketubah"; }
        $artistname=str_replace(' ','-',$artist_fullname);
        if (trim($artistname)=="Ze&#39;ev") {
        $artistname="Ze-ev"; }
        if (trim($artistname)=="This is not a Ketubah") {
        $artistname="This is not a Ketubah"; }
        $artist_path='meet-our-artists/'.strtolower($artistname);
 ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $artist_path; ?>"><span style="color:#FFF;font-weight:200;"><?php echo $artist_fullname; ?></span></a><br />
<?php } else { ?>
          <span style="color: #999; font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $products[$j]['model']; ?></span><br />
<?php } ?>
          <?php if ($display_price) { ?>
          <?php if (!$products[$j]['special']) { ?>
          <span style="color: #00d8ff; font-weight: bold;cursor:default;"><?php echo $products[$j]['price']; ?></span>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span style="color: #00d8ff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: line-through;"><?php echo $products[$j]['price']; ?></span> <span style="color: #FAA; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $products[$j]['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
</div>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <?php if ($products[$j]['rating']) { ?>
          <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars_<?php echo $products[$j]['rating'] . '.png'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $products[$j]['stars']; ?>" />
          <?php } ?>
                    <a class="cart_add" href="<?php echo $products[$j]['add']; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_add_to_cart; ?>" ><span><?php echo $button_add_to_cart; ?></span></a>

          <?php } ?>

          <!--<a href="<?php echo $add_to_wishlist; ?>" class="wish_add" rel="nofollow"><span><?php echo $button_to_wishlist; ?>+ Favorites</span></a>-->

          </td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>

    </table>
    <div class="pagination" style="width:950px;text-align:right"><?php
    if (($numpages-$ii)>1) {
     echo "Displaying all ".($numpages-$ii)." items in this category.";
     } else {
     echo "Displaying 1 item in this category.";
     } ?></div>
         <?php } ?>



  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Any help would be amazing!

Thank you in advance

Comment: And why don't You just use the Bestseller module - from `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` use it's `getBestsellerProducts` method (not quite sure about the method name).

Comment: Sorry thought that I stated the question:  I am attempting to have it sort by popularity limited to 1 specific product category (Category id:23) instead of what is currently sorts by which is the latest added.

what code do I need to implement to have the function where I can sort by the popularity via Purchased, or Viewed based on Category id 23?

The open cart that I am currently using unfortunately is highly customized and the stock functions tend to be ignored by the custom code.  This is why I need to manually create it.

again any help is more then appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I will just try to set up the query, the method You need to call and all around is upon You then.

This should be to get all (or first 10 when using `LIMIT 10`) the products from category 23 ordered by views descending

```
SELECT p.*, pd.*
FROM `product` p
LEFT JOIN `product_description` pd 
    ON p.`product_id` = pd.`product_id` 
        AND pd.`language_id` = {<YOUR_LANGUAGE_ID>}
LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` ptc 
    ON p.`product_id` = ptc.`product_id` 
        AND ptc.`category_id` = 23
ORDER BY p.`views` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Notice:** not sure about the `p.views` column name - check that before querying the DB.

If You would like to get all the products by the purchased count:

```
SELECT p.*, pd.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(op.product_id) 
        FROM `order_products` op 
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
    ) AS product_count
FROM `product` p
LEFT JOIN `product_description` pd 
    ON p.`product_id` = pd.`product_id` 
        AND pd.`language_id` = {<YOUR_LANGUAGE_ID>}
LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` ptc 
    ON p.`product_id` = ptc.`product_id` 
        AND ptc.`category_id` = 23
ORDER BY product_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Notice:** again I'm not sure about the `order_products` table name...

Try to launch the queries within phpMyAdmin and let me know if they are working or post an error message should there be any...